# In/On + Morning

Tags: prepositions

I encountered a phrase "**on a cold winter morning**".

Is it correct? I think It should be "**in a cold winter morning**".

---

e.g. *Sunrise on a cold winter morning outside Van Buren Hotel*

Comment: In the right context, either could work. Show us complete sentences.

Comment: Thanks tchrist. I've just edited the question. Look at the e.g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case two prepositions are competing, "in"and "on". We use "in" for the different times of a day, eg in the morning, in the afternoon, in the evening. Probably the concept "in the time of the morning" has an influence.

We use "on" when the word "day" is occurring as in "on a hot summer day", we use "on" in connection with the days of the week or when the concept of "day" has more influence than the concept of "time of the day".

So you find "on a cold winter morning" and not "in a cold winter morning".

By the way, "night" is a special case, it can be used with several prepositions.

Answer (score 1):

'On a cold winter morning' would make more sense in this context. 'On' is used for periods of the day and days of the week. If it was referring to seasons like 'winter', 'In winter ....' would make sense. There is no particular explanation that I know of to back this up. It's matter of memory,'On the bus','In the car' etc....

Answer (score 1):

Usually 'on' is used to refer to **something on the surface** and 'in' is used when the **subject lies within/inside something.**

In the given context, that something would be time. 
As explained in the previous answer, "in winter" makes more sense because we're talking about a season which goes on for an extended period, and specifying a more precise occurring within that whole period of winter is possible. 
In the case of a 'morning', however, things are different. The scope of giving a detailed event within a single day is way lesser than that of within a season. So, the preposition 'on' is used here, since ***the emphasis is on the date ( the morning being mentioned ) and not on the time.***