# What is the difference between "on a cold winter morning" and "in a cold winter morning"?

Tags: grammaticality, differences

What is the difference between "on a cold winter morning" and "in a cold winter morning"?
Which is correct or which sounds more natural?

Comment: Duplicate of another question closed: [**In/On + Morning**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272434/in-on-morning)

Comment: And elsewhere: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/on-a-cold-day-morning.3720326/

Answer (score 0):

An [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+a+cold+morning%2Cin+a+cold+morning%2Con+a+cold+day%2Cin+a+cold+day&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20a%20cold%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20cold%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20a%20cold%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20cold%20day%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Con%20a%20cold%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20cold%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20a%20cold%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20cold%20day%3B%2Cc0) shows that for "day" and "morning", usage has it that "on" is largely the predilected preposition, and therefore it sounds much more natural. You'll find that this is also verified for  the more particular "winter morning" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+a+cold+winter+morning%2Cin+a+cold+winter+morning&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20a%20cold%20winter%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20cold%20winter%20morning%3B%2Cc0)).

[image]

Let's now consider the word "spell", which is used for more general period of time, and we see that the exact opposite is true ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+a+cold+spell%2Cin+a+cold+spell&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20a%20cold%20spell%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20cold%20spell%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Con%20a%20cold%20spell%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20cold%20spell%3B%2Cc0)).

[image]

Semantically, there is no difference between what is expressed by one preposition and the other. The only difference is in the idiomaticity: in the first case "in" is not very idiomatic and in the second "on" is not.

This shows that the choice of preposition that becomes the preferred one (or "right" one) is dictated by how people perceive semantically the postposed noun. For the purpose of referring to the morning of the  day when the speaker talks, "in" is the only preposition used (in the morning); for a morning that is being referred to by means of a date, "on" is much preferred, but "in" is used with a not so negligible frequency. ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+morning+of%2Con+the+morning+of&share=&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3))

[image]

This shows that the choice is probably influenced by the idea of date, which is commonly expressed by means of the preposition "on". As regards the word "spell", which evokes the more general idea of a "volume" of time, it is "in" that appears to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

**On a cold winter morning** is correct

You only use **in** with **the** - e.g. **Tomorrow it will be cold in the morning**

**winter's morning** can be used as an alternative to **winter morning**. Although there is no hard and fast rule about it you would be more likely to use **winter's morning** when talking about seasonal phenomena. e.g.

**On a winter's morning I like the sparkle of the frost on the grass.**